# Getting function from within object function

Tags: javascript, oop

I've been learning OOP and playing around in JavaScript, and was wondering how to get something that looks like this to work...

```
function myApp(){

   this.nav = function(){

      function toggle(state = 'show'){
          //toggle nav code...
      }

   toggle(); 
   }


}

var app = new myApp();
app.nav();
```

How would go about accessing the toggle function from here like this...

```
app.nav().toggle('hide');
```

Comment: Your function would have to `return {toggle : function() {...}}` to be chainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return **this**.
here an example:

```
function myApp(){
    this.nav = function(){
    this.toggle = function(state = 'show'){
      console.log(state);      
    }   
    this.toggle();
    return this;
  }
}

const app = new myApp();
app.nav(); // show
app.nav().toggle('hide'); // show hide
```

Also you need to attach the function to the object (**this.toggle**).
hope this help.

Comment: thanks, I was playing around with this I came across this scenario, and was curious

Answer (score 1):

you should return the object to make the methods chainable.
your definition could be like:

```
function myApp(){
   var self= this;

   self.toggle = function(state = 'show'){
      //toggle nav code...
      //return self? to make it chainable too
   }

   self.nav = function(){
     self.toggle(); 
     return self;
   }
}

var app = new myApp();
app.nav();
```

but this is not the best implementation for oop :/

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer like this:

```
function myApp(){

   this.nav = function(){
      var core = {
          toggle: toggle
      }
      function toggle(state = 'show'){
          if(state === "show") 
          {
            console.log("showing state");
          } else {
            console.log(state);
          }        
      }
      return core;
    }
}

var app = new myApp();
app.nav().toggle();
app.nav().toggle('close');
```